# Evaluation of a passed function is slower than direct evaluation in julia. Is there a workaround?

Tags: julia

Say I have a lot of different very simple functions called f1, f2, ....
I would like to store all of the f functions in a fStruct and pass one of the f functions to e.g. g, when I need itin my code.
But when I pass the function f to g, the evaluation of the function g() is much slower.
Is there a workaround?
My ugly solution is to use an overall function which selects the right f() function by if-else statements.
Below is a minimal example of the slow computation.

```
using BenchmarkTools
struct fFunction
    f1
    f2
end
f() = return 1
fStruct = fFunction(f, f)
g = fStruct.f1
@btime f() --> 0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime g() --> 9.591 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

**EDIT1:**

I could also ask why the function g is slower or how to make it as fast as f in the following minimal example

```
using BenchmarkTools
f() = return 1
func = "f"
g = eval(Meta.parse(func))
f == g -->true
@btime f() --> 0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime g() --> 11.907 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

**EDIT2:**

Thank you for your answers.
I update the post with a solution.

```
using BenchmarkTools
f() = return 1
function g(x)
   h = f
   h()
end
const g2 = f
@btime f()
@btime g(f)
@btime g2()
```

f, g and g2 give you the same speed.

```
struct fFunctionAmbigiousType{F}
     f1::F
     f2::F
end
struct fFunctionDeclaredType{F}
     f1::F
     f2::F
end
fStructAmbigiousType = fFunctionAmbigiousType(f, f)
fStructDeclaredType = fFunctionDeclaredType(f, f)
fTuple = (f1 = f, f2 = f)
@btime $fStructAmbigiousType.f1
@btime $fStructDeclaredType.f1
@btime $fTuple.f1
fStructAmbigiousTypeFunctionPassed = fStructAmbigiousType.f1
fStructDeclaredTypeFunctionPassed = fStructDeclaredType.f1
fTupleFunctionPassed = fTuple.f1
@btime $fStructAmbigiousTypeFunctionPassed() 
@btime $fStructDeclaredTypeFunctionPassed() 
@btime $fTupleFunctionPassed()
```

fFunctionAmbigiousType, fFunctionDeclaredType and fTuple give you the same speed.
Declaring the type of a function to a struct does not change anything. Julia understands in both cases typeof{f}.
A paramteric struct or a parametric NamedTuple is possible, but is of course slower, if you apply the function often. If you apply the funcion f often you should pass it first to g or something like that to avoid the indexing every time.

Kind regards,
Till

Comment: I suspect this may have more to do with @btime than with f and g per se. If you try the standard `@time` macro you will get no difference. Further more, f and g evaluate to the same objects in memory (according to `objectid`), so there shouldn't be a difference in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues in your question.

#### How to do benchmarks

Actually in your code both functions are equally fast. The problem is that `g` is not `const` in global scope which introduces a penalty. To see this declare `g` as const or use `$g` in `@btime` call to see that there is no difference:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> struct fFunction
           f1
           f2
       end

julia> f() = return 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fStruct = fFunction(f, f)
fFunction(f, f)

julia> const g = fStruct.f1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime f()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @btime g()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1
```

and

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> struct fFunction
           f1
           f2
       end

julia> f() = return 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fStruct = fFunction(f, f)
fFunction(f, f)

julia> g = fStruct.f1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime f()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @btime $g()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1
```

#### How to analyze your code

However, this equivalence is artificial, because you extract `g` from `fStruct` in global scope thus it is evaluated before a call to `@btime`. A more proper test would be:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> struct fFunction
           f1
           f2
       end

julia> f() = return 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fStruct = fFunction(f, f)
fFunction(f, f)

julia> test1() = f()
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test2(fStruct) = fStruct.f1()
test2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime test1()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @btime test2($fStruct)
  14.462 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @code_warntype test1()
Body::Int64
1 1 ─     return 1                                                                                                                   │

julia> @code_warntype test2(fStruct)
Body::Any
1 1 ─ %1 = (Base.getfield)(fStruct, :f1)::Any                                                                           │╻ getproperty
  │   %2 = (%1)()::Any                                                                                                  │
  └──      return %2
```

And you see that using `fFunction` struct is not efficient because its `f1` and `f2` fields have abstract type (`Any` to be specific).

#### How to write an efficient struct that holds functions

Use either a `Tuple`, a `NamedTuple` or struct with parameters as they all provide type information. A tuple would be simply defined as `(f,f)`, a `NamedTuple` would be `(f1=f, f2=f)`. The most complex case is parametric struct, which I show you here (code for `Tuple` and `NamedTuple` would be even simpler):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> struct fFunction{F1,F2}
           f1::F1
           f2::F2
       end

julia> f() = return 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fStruct = fFunction(f, f)
fFunction{typeof(f),typeof(f)}(f, f)

julia> test1() = f()
test1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test2(fStruct) = fStruct.f1()
test2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @btime test1()
  0.001 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @btime test2($fStruct)
  1.866 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1

julia> @code_warntype test1()
Body::Int64
1 1 ─     return 1                                                                                                                   │

julia> @code_warntype test2(fStruct)
Body::Int64
1 1 ─     (Base.getfield)(fStruct, :f1)                                                                                 │╻ getproperty
  └──     return 1
```

And you can see that using `fFunction` defined as parametric type has almost no overhead (the only cost you pay is field extraction).

If something is not clear please let me know and I can elaborate more on it.

Comment: Nice answer with a lot of detail.

Comment: @Till just accept this answer if it answers your question. Please don't provide answers within questions, it is of no use to future users looking for similar questions since the question appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

If you know ahead of time what kind of function you will be passing, one thing I found to make things much faster is to manually transform the closure you need into a struct. So, if for example you will always be passing functions of the form

```
f(x) = x + a
```

for different `a`, you can transform this into

```
struct Adder
    a::Int
end

(adder::Adder)(x) = x + adder.a
```

and then use it in `fFunction` like

```
fFunction(f::Adder, g::Adder) = rand() < 0.5 ? f(10) : g(10)
```

That way, you have a concrete type for `f` and `g` and manual control over your closures, entirely avoiding all the method call overhead except for the overloaded call operator.  And `fFunction` is completely specialized and type-stable.

Comment: Do you mean that a is fixed for the specific function f, like f_a(x) = x + a? Then, my idea in the post above was similar in mind I think "My ugly solution is to use an overall function which selects the right f() function by if-else statements.". But why should it be faster with respect to the solution above? Due to multiple-dispatch the method call overhead should not be very much, or? At least in the second run.